# Hide API requests (YahooFinance) in Java Visual Studio Code debugger

Tags: java, visual-studio, maven, debugging

I have trouble to remove the orange java API requests in the debugger terminal. I want to hide these. How do I do this? (see picture)

I am using Visual Studio Code with maven.

[Printscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7U2H.jpg)

My code snippet:

```
        try {


    Calendar from = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar to = Calendar.getInstance();
    from.add(Calendar.YEAR, -1); // from 1 year ago 
    Stock stock = YahooFinance.get("GOOG");
    List<HistoricalQuote> stockHistQuotes = stock.getHistory(from, to, Interval.DAILY);

}

 catch(Exception e) {}
```

Output:

```
Hello World!
358 [main] INFO yahoofinance.quotes.query1v7.QuotesRequest - Sending request: https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/quote?symbols=GOOG
3687 [main] INFO yahoofinance.histquotes2.HistQuotes2Request - Sending request: https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/GOOG?period1=1510830000&period2=1542366000&interval=1d&crumb=FlUQht4hFF9
3756 [main] INFO yahoofinance.histquotes2.HistQuotes2Request - Parsing CSV line: 2017-11-16,1022.520020,1035.920044,1022.520020,1032.500000,1032.500000,1129700
3758 [main] INFO yahoofinance.histquotes2.HistQuotes2Request - Parsing CSV line: 2017-11-17,1034.010010,1034.420044,1017.750000,1019.090027,1019.090027,1397100
3758 [main] INFO yahoofinance.histquotes2.HistQuotes2Request - Parsing CSV line: 2017-11-20,1020.260010,1022.609985,1017.500000,1018.380005,1018.380005,953500
```

Everything but Hello World should be removed.

Comment: Please add a sample of the output into the question, not as a picture.

Comment: What logging library are you using? Check the documentation for your library to see how to change logging level for specific classes/packages.  For example, in log4j, you could set a logger in your config file to only log `ERROR` and worse for `yahoofinance`.

Comment: I am using: <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
       <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
       <version>1.6.4</version>
   </dependency>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you I solved it with using this line of code:

```
Configurator.setRootLevel(Level.FATAL);
```

And changed my dependencies in maven to:

```
 <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.1</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.1</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-1.2-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.1</version>
  </dependency>
```